# Why is page using CSS columns reflowing on load?

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I have a single page using CSS columns that reflows on load.

Even when I remove all IMGs and iFrames, so it is fetching no
external resources, it reflows.

I can't figure out what is causing the reflow/repaint. Any CSS exports
out there able to figure this one out?

https://github.com/treenotation/dumbdown/issues/8

Comment: Are you using flex box? I've noticed it inverts the order of elements depending on flex-direction/justify-content/align-items

Comment: I am not using Flexbox or either of those 2 properties. The full HTML and CSS is visible in this single page: https://breckyunits.com/

Answer (score 2):

There's too much content in document.

The browser will gradually display the content, that is, the content involved in rendering will gradually increase, which affects the layout calculation.

[image: chrome performance tool]

You can add the "loading state" style. When `window.onload` Event trigger, change the style to "load complete".

Or '[Masonry Layout](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-3/)'.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for the reflow is: a huge amount of content but NO strategy to handle with. Indeed there are many things you can avoid/do/change ...

**REASON WHY - just to base the answer ...**

The reflow is caused by the mechanic: at first the text (html code) has been downloaded and rendered. But there are still a lot of elements (most over images but youtube videos and iframes as well) which are still on download. As the browser don't know the size of that elements he does not keep the place for that elements.

Now: after the download and rendering of every element has finished the browser injects the element to the content and all off the following content is pushed down and in your case to next column ... reflow.

**STRATEGY: MULTIPLE ACTIONS**

To your question: there is not only one reason which causes multiple and long downloads. So far there is no simple single answer and even NOT A SINGLE SOLUTION. Your needed strategy will be to optimize the page by a multiple bundle of actions. But I believe doing that you can reduce it to an acceptable amount ... and maybe there is a chance.

**THINGS YOU CAN DO**

**1. Change layout**

If you change the layout to an actual web technique. That means don't use columns (flowing left to right) to a style which prepares the pageflow from up to down. Than you can asynchron load the needed elements when the user scrolls down. The technique is named `Infinite scrolling`: [How to do an infinite scroll in plain Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456846/how-to-do-an-infinite-scroll-in-plain-javascript/6457592)

But I assume as the special layout has charm this won't be an option for you!?

**2. Images which are not shown - remove not needed elements from download**

On your page I found images which are downloaded but which are not shown on the page. (Example: `3.png` with `INCREDIBILE USELESS 659KB`). Remove such elements from your content.

**3. Reduce not needed size of elements**

Additional a lot of shown images on your page have an incredibly large file size which is not needed.

Example: `devices.png`
image-size: `692x285px - real size`
layout-size: `287x118px - needed size`
file-size-download: `110kb`
file-size-needed: `4kb - if (lossless) optimized`

And think about: many little file downloads add up to a big amount ... and you have a lot of downloads! If you calculate: **10 images your way: 1.1 MB can be done with 40KBs**

*Additional:*

- if you you need higher solutions use `srcset` attributes ...
- sometimes that is a practical problem with the knowledge of the editors: than teach them how to lossless reduce images and advise them the sizes to use for the images in the layout

**4. Use faster server for images**

It seems the download rate from your server is not the fastest one. That's normal by most providers. As you have a lot of images ... think about to load images from a faster server - if possible. Example: the pure download service from AWS (Amazon Web Service) is incredibly fast. As you just need a bucket for downloading that is not as expensive ... try it out.

**5. Use placeholders for elements**

As you have a lot of elements I think you maybe cannot avoid the later injection which causes the reflow. But you can use placeholders for your element so the needed place is reserved and the reflow still does not happen for this element.

Just define the html structure and possible sizes in your layout. That additional helps the editors as they know what image size they can use. Then size the placeholders with CSS and initiate an ajax image download by JS.

In case of later download now the users maybe see a placeholder at the beginning but no reflow. You can do that with few lines of code. I attach an example at the end of the posting.

**NOTE:** You can do this with (youtube-)videos or iframes in a similar way ;-)

**6. Use vanilla instead of jQuery**

As I saw has the download of jQuery an incredible impact to your download time. Really. (That's the reason why I assume your server is a slower one.) Have a look to the download time of your elements. It is one of the elements which needs the most times and blocks your elements from rendering.

jQuery is an old dog. Modern web techniques use vanilla JS ... and as I see there are no complicated things on your page you cannot realize in vanilla. So the recommendation is to remove it from you page (if possible) and you will earn a huge speed advantage.

**7. Use CDNs for download when possible**

Downloading frameworks and fonts from own server makes pages slow and blocks time for the page download of other elements. Use a CDN instead.

As I have seen your fonts are loaded from a CDN? But jQuery still comes from your server. If you don't want to change to vanilla chose to load it from CDN.

**8. Check if Youtube can be loaded more simple**

Youtube is loaded by several actions to your page. In this case I AM NOT SURE as I still did not work with youtube for a longer time. But I believe (not sure if I am right) that there is a more direct way to include youtube videos to a page. Maybe you would like to check it.

But nevertheless: work with placeholders for the video players as well. That are almost just few additional lines off css.

**9. Optimizing user experience: thinking about a preloader**

Reflow is not new phenomenon to webpages. Up to now a lot of pages uses preloaders to generate a better user experience. Today's technique is ajax load...

I don't know if the described techniques will avoid the reflow completely. As there are many elements the download time cannot be set to zero. But optimizing the page will reduce it dramatically. If there still remains a little bit ... maybe you like to think about the older technique. Using a nice and maybe well designed preloader symbol indeed can upgrade the user experience. Maybe on mobile views with medium data speed there is no other chance...?

But that is just to think about an additional possibility ...

**[update]**
**10. Combine placeholder with infinite scroll**

If you are using `placeholders` you can/should `combine it with technique infinite scroll`.

Means: all media (particularly images but maybe videos and iframes as well) are prepositioned by sized placeholders. That works immediately so there should be no more reflow as needed. Then load media assynchron by AJAX based on their position on their screen. Images which are in view are loaded immediately.

As you don't have so many media elements on starting viewport (most are still below the screen view) that should work as if it is a page with a 'normal number' of pictures/medias.

All others are loading afterwards when scrolling the page the media comes in view like on a 'infinite scroll page'. (Note: that works if the file size off the images is not to large, - so optimizing the images has still to be done.)

That has the additional advantage that thake makes sure that the images are loaded in the sequence they are needed ... which safes a lot of time.

Could be done in javascript:

1. Place images/media by placeholder technique
2. On `window.onload` check which images/media are in the viewport. Don't forget images which are only partly seen.
3. On `window.onscroll` check if image(s) comes to viewport and load image

**Note:** I am not quite sure if there are anchor links on your page to the single articles. I believe not. But if you still use them the starting viewport can be anywhere on the page when the user call an article. In that case `window.onscroll` has not only to work scrolling down but scrolling up to.

I am not quite sure if there is a ready script avaiable. But I would wonder if not. Otherwise it would not be to tricky to do that on your own. That would have the charm that such scripts mostly have less and cleaner code than preworked scripts ...
**[end update]**

**... ... ...**

I am not quite sure if the described issues are complete. Mostly there are found more possibilities to optimize a page when you start with the process. But as I had a nearer look to your page that are the most important chances.

---

**EXAMPLE LAZY IMAGE LOAD WITH PLACEHOLDER EFFECT**

Just EASY AND SIMPLIFIED example for lazy image load. Please adapt to your need.

```
// new html for image
<img class="placeholder-size" src="path/placeholder.jpg" data-lazy-url="https://url-to-your/imag.png" alt="Image Description">

// css
.placeholder-size {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
}

// js for lazy load
// older code but works, please actualize if needed
window.onload = function(){
    var lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll('[data-lazy-url]');
    for (var i in lazyImages) if (lazyImages.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        var imgUrl = lazyImages[i].getAttribute('data-lazy-url');
        lazyImages[i].src=imgUrl;
    };
};
```