# How to add custom scroll behaviour to page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, custom-scrolling

I was wondering if anybody knows how to achieve a scrolling effect as seen on this page:
https://plastic.design/

I don't know what this effect is called and don't even know how to describe it, which makes it pretty hard to google it.

edit:
this question has been marked as a duplicate of [How to do an infinite scroll in plain Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6456846/20888045). These question do not ask for the same functionality – one asks for an infinite scroll, mine simply asks about some sort of a delayed scrolling behaviour.

Comment: You can use [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap/). GSAP is a robust JavaScript toolset that turns developers into animation superheroes.

Comment: That's right, GSAP offers the ScrollSmoother library – but this is behind a paywall. Do you happen to know any free alternatives?