# What is the logic behind the article infinity scroll on Bloomberg website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I recreate an article details page like "Bloomberg" in ReactJS? When scrolling down, the new related article loads.

Is there anywhere I can find related info or example/clone codes?

https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2023-04-11/australia-s-new-city-bradfield-faces-climate-change-challenges

Comment: Did you give it a shot? if so, where did you get stuck? Lots of infinite scroll examples on the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic of infinite scroll is to monitor the [position of the scrollbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) of a container by using the `onscroll` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event). Once the [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) is almost at the end of the [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight), let's say 80%, we could trigger an XHR/fetch to get more information from the server and render the new result on the UI.

If you are interested in building it in Vanilla JS, you could refer to [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456846/how-to-do-an-infinite-scroll-in-plain-javascript).

If you are interested in building it with ReactJS, you could refer to [this post](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-infinite-scroll).

In my previous experience, we might call Bloomburg's implementation the `load-on-demand` with a scrollbar position criteria. So, the rendering and data loading are synced, you could find it through the browser's dev tool. If we already got a lot of data and would like to provide a shorter time to interact, we might render the element on demand, for example [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/example) gives an awesome performance on 100K rows on the UI.